# Boostrap-5 carousel is not working as it should be

Tags: html, xcode, performance, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm learning to build websites, and I'm been doing it by myself with tutorials and stuff. I'm in the part of learning to use bootstrap, but when I try to use the carousel it doesn't work, the slide get stocked in the first picture and no matter how much I wait or how much I push any of the bottons, it does not work.

This is the code from the site, I got the link in my code but it does not work, while others elements from the site, work perfectly:

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [bootstrap.min.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) and [bootstrap.bundle.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js) CDN references to the project

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo</title>
    
    <!-- Add the following CDN reference -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Add the following CDN reference -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### References

- [Get started with Bootstrap v5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/)
- [Carousel with Bootstrap v5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/)

Comment: Thanks, I added the last part, the one with the script. I gonna need to explore a bit more about it, because the tutorial that I was following just took the code directly from Bootstrap and just worked, with no more.